# Tried to solve the "Close Far" exercise

Tags: java

Given three ints, a b c, return true if one of b or c is "close" (differing from a by at most 1), while the other is "far", differing from both other values by 2 or more. Note: Math.abs(num) computes the absolute value of a number.

```
closeFar(1, 2, 10) → true
closeFar(1, 2, 3) → false
closeFar(4, 1, 3) → true
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service

Comment: Please read the page on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show that you've actually tried to solve the problem by yourself by including a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to compare a with both b and c (`using Math.abs(a-b)` and `using Math.abs(a-c)`) and then check if the other values differ by at least 2. Something like this:

```
    public static boolean closeFar(int a, int b, int c) {
                return ( (Math.abs(a-b) == 1 && (Math.abs(a-c) >= 2 && Math.abs(b-c) >= 2) ||
                         (Math.abs(a-c) == 1 && (Math.abs(a-b) >= 2 && Math.abs(b-c) >= 2)))
                       );
    }
```

Test cases:

```
        System.out.println(closeFar(1,2,10)); //prints true
        System.out.println(closeFar(1,2,3)); //prints false
        System.out.println(closeFar(4,1,3)); //prints true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working!!!

Comment: Sure, but technically I can not upvote